# Problem with coordinate system and displaced Text in different PDFs using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, coordinate-systems

I'm working with iTextSharp and .NET 3.5 SP1 (in C#, as you can guess) and modify some existing PDFs using the `PdfStamper` class. Now I've got two problems:

**Transforming the coordinate system**

As I see it, iTextSharp is using (postscript?) points as unit of measurement, but I'd like to transform these coordinates to millimeter. Now, how's the best way to achieve this?

Taking a look in the documentation revealed the following approach:

```
PdfContentByte cb = new PdfContentByte();
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix scale = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix(
    0.352777778, 0, 0.352777778, 0, 0, 0); // 1 point = 0.352777778 mm
cb.Transform(scale);
```

I hope I got the transformation matrix right. But the problem is: There is no `System.Drawing.Drawing2D` Assembly! Was this assembly dropped or what happened to it? What can I do to transform the coordinates of iTextSharp to millimeter. Am I on the wrong way here?

**Text in PDF gets displaced in a different PDF using the same coordinates**

I noticed that while modifying *two different* PDF files with the *same content*, that the same coordinates got displaced and the text is not being placed at the exact same positions. What is causing this and how can I prevent it?

This is the first PDF:

[image]

This is the second PDF, created using the exact same coordinates in iTextSharp:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the problem is: There is no
>   System.Drawing.Drawing2D Assembly! Was
>   this assembly dropped or what happened
>   to it? What can I do to transform the
>   coordinates of iTextSharp to
>   millimeter. Am I on the wrong way
>   here?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.aspx (in System.Drawing.dll)

Comment: How do I use this class? I already inserted a "using System.Drawing;" statement, but it still does not recognize System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix. I'm not sure what "in System.Drawing.dll" means. Do I have to include this in some other way?

Comment: You have to reference System.Drawing.Dll.  In your project, find the  References folder.  Right click, Add reference, then after five minutes, search for System.Drawing.Dll in the first tab.  Now give me back my 2 points!

Comment: Once you've referenced it, you can use it just like in the example.  They're doing matrix transforms, which isn't exactly the easiest thing to learn or understand.  You'll have to do some reading up on your own if you want to do more than the sample code demonstrates, I'm afraid.

Comment: With pleasure, but you have to edit your post before I can upvote it. Best you put your explanation from the comment in the posting so other users see it directly.
Thanks! :)

Comment: 1) they can see it 2) its fundamental 3) I'm lazy

Comment: Then I am afraid I can't upvote you since SO does not allow to change a downvote to an upvote for old posts. But it's okay I guess as you did your best to deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved the second problem with the text being displaced despite the same coordinates being used.

As it turned out, the first PDF included some non-visible trimming space, the second didn't. The trimming space isn't visible 'cause the view space was cropped using the PDF creator, but as it appears the trimming space was still there and counted for the coordinates.